# Extracting nested JSON with SQL

Tags: json, sql-server

I am having trouble retrieving all the values of the "url" key in this JSON

```
{  
   "vehicles":[  
      {  
         "vehicle":{  
            "media":{  
               "videos":[  

               ],
               "images":[  
                  {  
                     "url":"testURL1",
                     "position":1
                  },
                  {  
                     "url":"testURL2",
                     "position":2
                  }
               ],
               "imageCount":null,
               "merchandizedImages":null,
               "merchandizedImageCount":null,
               "fyuseIds":null
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         "vehicle":{  
            "media":{  
               "videos":[  

               ],
               "images":[  
                  {  
                     "url":"testingURL3",
                     "posiiton":"1"
                  },
                  {  
                     "url":"testingURL4",
                     "position":"2"
                  }
               ],
               "imageCount":null,
               "merchandizedImages":null,
               "merchandizedImageCount":null,
               "fyuseIds":null
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I am able to get the value of individual items with

```
select @content = value from openjson(@json)
select [url] as imgURL
    from openjson(@content) 
    with (
        [url] nvarchar(max) '$.vehicle.media.images[0].url'
    )
```

but I don't always know the number of elements in images and I also don't know the number of total vehicles.

I can get all the urls for the first vehicle with

```
select @content = value from openjson(@json)
    select @vehicle = vehicle from openjson(@content) with (vehicle nvarchar(max) as json)
    select @media = media from openjson(@vehicle) with (media nvarchar(max) as json)
    select @images = images from openjson(@media) with (images nvarchar(max) as json)
select [url] as imgURL
    from openjson(@images) 
    with (
        [url] nvarchar(max)
    )
```

but cant get the next vehicle and so on

Comment: What is the end result you are after here?

Comment: Also, for that JSON i get the error `JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 600.`: [db<>fiddke](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9d7db4463efe034fba7635b4e48ec8d8). Is that your actual JSON? If so, you won't get any results from it.

Comment: I corrected the JSON, thanks. As for the end result, I need to return a column for each vehicle with all the urls associated with the vehicle in the column, I'm not sure that will work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the JSON you provided is hosed. Not only are your key names spelled differently (e.g. position vs posiiton ), but your JSON is not valid, so matter what you do, you won't get the expected result(s). Or worse, you'll get results, but wrong ones.

(**note**: you've since corrected this)

Regardless, this is what your JSON **should** look like:

```
{"vehicles":[
  {"vehicle": {
      "media": {
        "videos":[],
        "images":[{ "url":"testingURL1", "position":"1" },{ "url": "testingURL2", "position":"2" }],
        "imageCount":4,
        "merchandizedImages":null,
        "merchandizedImageCount":null,
        "fyuseIds":null
      }
    }
  },
  {"vehicle": {
    "media": {  
      "videos":[],
      "images":[{ "url":"testingURL3", "position":"1" }, { "url":"testingURL4", "position":"2" }],
      "imageCount":4,
      "merchandizedImages":null,
      "merchandizedImageCount":null,
      "fyuseIds":null
    }
  }}
]}
```

Once your JSON is correct, you can query it as needed.

Here is a completed example you can run in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @VehicleJSON VARCHAR(MAX) = '{"vehicles":[{"vehicle":{"media":{"videos":[],"images":[{"url":"testingURL1","position":"1"},{"url":"testingURL2","position":"2"}],"imageCount":4,"merchandizedImages":null,"merchandizedImageCount":null,"fyuseIds":null}}},{"vehicle":{"media":{"videos":[],"images":[{"url":"testingURL3","position":"1"},{"url":"testingURL4","position":"2"}],"imageCount":4,"merchandizedImages":null,"merchandizedImageCount":null,"fyuseIds":null}}}]}';

SELECT
    imageCount, merchandizedImages, merchandizedImageCount, fyuseIds, imageUrl, imagePosition
FROM OPENJSON( @VehicleJSON, '$.vehicles' )
WITH (
    imageCount INT '$.vehicle.media.imageCount',
    merchandizedImages VARCHAR(255) '$.vehicle.media.merchandizedImages',
    merchandizedImageCount INT '$.vehicle.media.merchandizedImageCount',
    fyuseIds VARCHAR(255) '$.vehicle.media.fyuseIds',
    Images NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.vehicle.media.images' AS JSON
) AS Vehicles
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON( Images )
WITH (
    imageUrl VARCHAR(255) '$.url',
    imagePosition INT '$.position'
);
```

Which returns:

```
+------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------+-------------+---------------+
| imageCount | merchandizedImages | merchandizedImageCount | fyuseIds |  imageUrl   | imagePosition |
+------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------+-------------+---------------+
|          4 | NULL               | NULL                   | NULL     | testingURL1 |             1 |
|          4 | NULL               | NULL                   | NULL     | testingURL2 |             2 |
|          4 | NULL               | NULL                   | NULL     | testingURL3 |             1 |
|          4 | NULL               | NULL                   | NULL     | testingURL4 |             2 |
+------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

This should get you moving in the right direction.

A quick little note on this line:

```
Images NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.vehicle.media.images' AS JSON
```

When using **AS JSON** in this scenario, the datatype must be **NVARCHAR**. You'll get an exception telling you this if you define it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

At a total guess (and there is probably a better way) is this what you're after?

```
SELECT u.[url],
       u.position
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON) 
     WITH (vehicles nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) J
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.[vehicles]) 
                 WITH (vehicle nvarchar(MAX) '$.vehicle' AS JSON) v
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(v.vehicle)
                 WITH (media nvarchar(MAX) '$.media' AS JSON) m
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(m.media)
                 WITH (images nvarchar(MAX) '$.images' AS JSON) i
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(i.images)
                 WITH([url] nvarchar(MAX) '$.url',
                      position int '$.position') u;
```

Note that `'testingURL3'` returns `NULL` for `position`, as the node doesn't exist (it has the node `posiiton`).

If not, then show what you're after, lie I asked before.